# configuring permission of directory in Linux

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

How to configure Permission of a directory that i created in / named as ENTRY such that who create contents in that directory can only modify that contents. I am using RHEL 7

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "contents in directory"? File permissions govern if one can modify data, the file content. Directory permissions govern if one can modify some metadata (like name), directory entries. Also "one can only modify" may be "only this user" or "only this action: modification (but not removal)". Please [edit] the question and clarify, state your needs more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for setting the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) on the directory. As for the file contents, the permissions of the individual files would govern who can modify the file contents.